# Performance Lack in my C++ Code

Tags: c++, performance

At the moment i'm trying to optimize my c++ code to get better performance, because I have a strong java/c# background.
I've tested simple examples like getter/setter between classes and realized using them with references like this:

```
vector<string>& MyClass::getNum()
{
   return num;
}

void MyClass::setNum(vector<string> &num)
{
   this->num = num;
}
```

(let say 15+ Strings are in the Vector)

is faster 2x faster than without. (no difference when using simple/small parameter, but huge diff. when using Vectors etc.)

I also tried the same example in Java, but somehow my Java code is still faster than in C++.
Someone can help me?

Comment: Curious to see your benchmark.

Comment: What optimization level have you been using?

Comment: This question currently lacks a lot of information to be answerable. The only thing answers could currently do is speculate.

Comment: There should not be a difference between `int&` and `int` performance wise unless your optimization level is too low

Comment: @jasal He said the difference was visible mainly with big structure like vectors.

Comment: @Holt Right, I missed that.

Comment: @Sleicreider Does your code using reference in C++ run faster than the Java one?

Comment: @Holt he never said such thing. He said "when using vectors" which is a meaningless statement. That *may* mean that you replace `int` with `vector`, but it could also mean that he's iterating over a vector and getting every element. This question is simply too vague.

Comment: edited my code. int  and &int is no difference = true (like I wrote in the text) but using vector with data = big difference.

Comment: We cannot review code we don't see.

Comment: There's a simple answer to this... other languages do implicit reference counting of complex objects, but in C++ you'd need to use a `std::shared_pointer` to do this.  Both versions of the code in the question do some full-vector-data copying, so they're naturally slower.  (Answers that limit themselves to by-value, references and pointers will necessarily make compromises about ownership management / lifetimes that get much more complicated to explain.)

Comment: using pointers instead of references, seems to be faster

Answer (score 2):

In java, everything is pointer, so when you do this in java:

```
void function (ArrayList <Integer> myList);
```

It's almost equivalent in C++ to:

```
void function (std::vector <int> & myList);
void function (std::vector <int> * myList);
```

This answer your question on why Java is faster when not using reference in C++, because references are faster in most cases. Then, why does it improve performance?

Well, imagine you have a vector of int, if you pass it to a function without reference, you have to make a copy of the object (call the copy constructor), which take (in general) a huge amount of time since you  have to allocate a new array, etc. Another example with a struct:

```
struct X {
    int a[100] ;
    int b[100] ;
} ;
```

This struct take something like `2 * 100 * 4 = 800` bytes on a modern machine (may vary of course), so if you pass it to a function like that:

```
void function (X x) ;
```

When you call the function, you need to make a copy, so a copy of `800 bytes`, if you do:

```
void function (X const& x) ;
```

You only pass a reference to the object, i.e. something pointing to the object, which will take (on a x64 architecture), 8 bytes.

Comment: He never asks "Why there are no difference in C# and Java?". He's asking why his Java code is faster than his C++ code. Nothing about C#.

Comment: I've tried to use function parameter with reference, no difference at all.

Comment: I've also found this text somewhere: Because references are typically implemented by C++ using pointers, and dereferencing a pointer is slower than accessing it directly, accessing values passed by reference is slower than accessing values passed by value.

Answer (score 1):

`this->num = num;` : this line *copies* the vector you passed by reference. If your goal is to give the vector to `MyClass` and then forget about it, consider passing it by rvalue reference and *moving* it.

Comment: Or, much better, pass it by value and then move it.

Comment: @Puppy Won't that also make a copy ?

Comment: @Quentin no. Passing by value invokes move constructor if possible. All in all, if you want to *store* something, you need an *instance* of that something, and the "most outside" way to place that instance is in parameter list. Refer to [this question of mine](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10836221/should-i-write-constructors-using-rvalues-for-stdstring).

Comment: @BartekBanachewicz so if my understanding is correct, passing by value means that I get either a copy of the argument or the argument itself, depending on whether the caller wants to keep it or not ? Neat !