# When should I choose copy elision over passing argument by const reference?

Tags: c++, c++11, lvalue, rvalue, rvo

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is pass-by-value a reasonable default in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11)

I'm reading [Want Speed? Pass by Value.](http://cpp-next.com/archive/2009/08/want-speed-pass-by-value/) by Dave Abrahams about copy elision and RVO. And I'm wondering why do we need the copy elision?

I have been told too many times that you should pass function arguments by const reference to avoid copying (nearly every c++ book I read told me about this).

Suppose we have two functions:

```
int f1(const string &s);
int f2(string s);
```

If the actual argument is an rvalue, copying will be avoided in both functions. But if the actual argument is an lvalue, copying will only be avoided in f1, not in f2. So why do we need this feature?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Pass by value if you need a copy anyway. Whether you choose f1's signature or f2's signature depends upon the contents of the function.  For example, you would use a const reference in this case:

```
int f1(const string& s) {
    return s.size();
}
```

But you would pass by value in this case:

```
int f2(string s) {
    sort(s.begin(), s.end());
    s.erase(unique(s.begin(), s.end()), s.end());
    return s.size();
}
```

because the alternative would be this:

```
int f2(const string& s) {
    string temp(s);
    sort(temp.begin(), temp.end());
    temp.erase(unique(temp.begin(), temp.end()), temp.end());
    return temp.size();
}
```

Comment: One note: the latter case often occurs in constructors. Given `struct S { S(...): s(s) {} std::string s; };`, then it's better to use `std::string s` in place of `...` rather than a `std::string const& s` since there will be a copy anyway.

Comment: @MatthieuM: But make sure you move it into the member, not copy it. i.e. `S(std::string s): s(std::move(s)) {}`

Answer (score 1):

RVO doesn't apply to your example because the return value is `int`.

```
string f1(const string &s) {
    string ret = s; // always makes a copy
    ret += 'x';
    return ret; // makes a copy pre-C++11 if no RVO
}
```

Tally: 1-2 copies in C++03, exactly 1 in C++11 plus (if elision is disabled) a move which may degenerate to a copy for some other class than `std::string`.

```
string f2(string s) { // calling makes a copy if lvalue or no elision
    s += 'x';
    return s; // makes a copy pre-C++11 if no RVO
}
```

Tally: 0-2 copies in C++03, or 0-1 in C++11.

As others have said, pass by value when you want to manipulate the object as a pure value, without any reference semantics.

`const &` is a familiar idiom, but it's a bit of a kludge in terms of language semantics. You use it when you don't want a reference at all; the `&` just serves to make the `const` meaningful in the parameter definition. If you want to modify the parameter (but only locally), then `const` doesn't really apply, and also the `&` drops out too.

Answer (score 0):

`f2` signals by its signature, no matter what you pass to me, I will deal with my own copy of your object. Useful, if `f2` is going to modify the object in a non reversible way (e.g. steal it's resources by moving), or in some concurrency scenarios. Admittedly, c++11 adds new level of confusion to the (already confusing) c++ type system but once you think about it makes a lot of sense...