# How to use std::transform without violating MISRA C++ 2008 Advisory Rule 5-2-10?

Tags: c++, misra

I get these error in PC-Lint (au-misra-cpp.lnt):

> ConverterUtil.cpp(90):
>   error 864: (Info -- Expression involving variable 'transformValue'
>   possibly depends on order of evaluation [**MISRA C++ Rule 5-2-10**])
>
> ConverterUtil.cpp(90):
>   error 864: (Info -- Expression involving variable 'transformValue'
>   possibly depends on order of evaluation [**MISRA C++ Rule 5-2-10**])
>
> ConverterUtil.cpp(90):
>   error 534: (Warning -- Ignoring return value of function
>   'std::transform(std::_String_iterator>>,
>   std::_String_iterator>>,
>   std::_String_iterator>>, int
>   (*)(int))' (compare with line 998, file C:\Program Files
>   (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 11.0\VC\include\algorithm) [MISRA C++
>   Rules 0-1-7 and 8-4-6], [MISRA C++ Rule 0-3-2])

On this code:

```
/**Conversion from std::string to bool*/
bool ConverterUtil::ConvertStdStringToBool(const std::string value)
{
    std::string transformValue = value;
    bool retValue = false;

    std::transform(transformValue.begin(), transformValue.end(), transformValue.begin(), &::tolower);


    if(transformValue == std::string(static_cast<const char *>("true")))
    {
        retValue = true;
    }

    return retValue;
}
```

I guessed it didn't like the fact that I use the same std::string as input and output in the transform, but using an other string as output gives the same error.

Is it possible to make the std::transform MISRA compliant?

Comment: Unrelated, but because you're passing `value` by-value to your function, the `tranformValue` local is unneeded. You already have a temp copy in `value`. You can forego the `const` on the parameter and use `value` in your code instead of `tranformValue` (though I would recc keeping it as-is but making the param a const-ref).

Comment: Maybe it wants you to copy the `begin()` and `end()` iterators, and pass the copies to `std::transform`.

Comment: If you only want an case insensitive compare look here for a lot of answers http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635/case-insensitive-string-comparison-in-c

Comment: @WhozCraig: In this particular case, pass by-value is better than pass by ref-to-const. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7592741/1137388). Otherwise, I agree with everything else that you said.

Comment: @CassioNeri yeah, I concur. Its a consistence thing with me, hard habit to break when it so-often is done by const-ref. Agreed.

Comment: @JanHerrmann +1 for an alternative solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm just guessing here (and I'll probably remove the answer if it doesn't solve your problem).

Try to replace the line containning `std::transform` with these two:

```
auto dest = transformValue.begin();
std::transform(transformValue.cbegin(), transformValue.cend(), dest, &::tolower);
```

Notice the use of `cbegin()` and `cend()` (rather than `begin()` and `end()`).

**On another topic**: You're copying the string passed to `ConvertStdStringToBool` twice when you could do it just once. To do this, replace:

```
bool ConverterUtil::ConvertStdStringToBool(const std::string value)
{
    std::string transformValue = value;
```

with

```
bool ConverterUtil::ConvertStdStringToBool(std::string transformValue)
{
```

(You might want to rename `transformValue` to `value` after this change).

**Update:** My explanation why I think it's going to help.

First of all, notice that `transformValue` is non `const`. Hence, `transformValue.begin()` and `transformValue.end()` will call these overloads:

```
iterator begin(); // non const overload
iterator end();   // non const overload
```

Hence the static analyser (rightly) concludes that `begin()` and `end()` might change the state of `transformValue`. In this case, the final state of `transformValue` might depend on which of `begin()` and `end()` is called first.

Now, when you call `cbegin()` and `cend()`, the overloads are these:

```
const_iterator cbegin() const; // notice the const 
const_iterator cend() const;   // notice the const
```

In this case, the static analyser will not deduce that these calls will change the state of `transformValue` and doesn't raise the issue. (Strictly speaking even though the methods are `const` they could change the state because there could exist `mutable` data members in the class or the methods could use an evil `const_cast`. IMHO, the static analyser shouldn't be blamed for that.)

Final remark: The call

```
std::transform(transformValue.cbegin(), transformValue.cend(), transformValue.cbegin(), &::tolower);
                                                                              ^^^^^^
```

is wrong. The third argument **must** be the non `const` iterator, that is, it **must** be `transformValue.begin()` (only the first two arguments are the `c*` methods).

However, I guess, for a similar reasoning as above, just using `transformValue.begin()` as the third argument won't be enough and that's why I suggested creating another variable (`dest`).

Comment: Whats difference between using begin() end() and cbegin() and cbegin() cend()? Because that's all it takes to make it happy:
std::transform(transformValue.cbegin(), transformValue.cend(), transformValue.cbegin(), &::tolower);

Comment: @MathiasWestin `cbegin()` returns a `const_iterator`. Frankly I'm shocked your output iterator as a const-iterator even *compiles*. Are you sure that isn't just `begin()` in your code (the third param)?

Comment: @WhozCraig Your are right it doesen't compile, I was happy that PCLint didn't throw any errors! :) So it has to be the way you show in the sample above.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a separate answer, more like a comment on Cassio's answer, but it's too long for a comment.

Here's how directly using `transformValue.begin()` as the third parameter could actually easily fail: in C++03 (not in 11, but GCC so far hasn't switched), a reference-counted implementation of std::string was allowed. libstdc++ has one. With such a version, `value` and `transformValue` would share their internal buffer.

Now, when `transformValue.begin()` is called, the resulting non-const iterator can be used to modify the buffer, which would be bad because it would change `value` too. So `begin()` has to unshare the buffer, i.e. allocate a unique buffer just for `transformValue`. Doing so **invalidates** all existing iterators!

Thus, in the C++98 version of calling `cbegin` and `cend`:

```
const std::string& constValue = transformValue;
std::transform(constValue.begin(), constValue.end(),
               transformValue.begin(), &::tolower);
```

you have got a real order dependency. If the non-const version of `begin()` is called before the const calls, everything is fine. But if the const version (or `end()`) is called first, the newly returned iterators will be invalidated by the non-const call, yielding undefined behavior.

Nastily enough, the code will still probably work, because the invalidated iterators would point to the old buffer, which is kept alive by `value`. Since in the majority of cases where such unsharing happens, the old copy will be around longer than the new copy, this is a really nasty sleeper bug that won't surface until either

- the old copy can disappear during the operation, e.g. because the old copy already went away, but another copy exists on another thread and could disappear at any time, or
- the code is changed in a way that expects the changes made through the non-const iterator to be reflected in the const iterators (which point to a different buffer and thus won't see them).

Answer (score 0):

Although the iterator begin() and end() are constant in this call, the checker suspects side effects from calling these. So the result *might* be different depending on the sequence of calls. I had a similar problem and had to fix it by using two local variables to shut up the checker.