# Why can't I pass this class as a reference when returned from arithmetic operators?

Tags: c++, c++11, operator-overloading, pass-by-reference

If I have a simple class like this:

```
template<typename T>
class coord
{
public:

    coord() : x(0), y(0)
    {
    }

    coord(T X, T Y) : x(X), y(Y)
    {
    }

    T x;
    T y;

    coord& operator-=(const coord& rhs)
    {
        (*this).x -= rhs.x;
        (*this).y -= rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }

    coord& operator+=(const coord& rhs)
    {
        (*this).x += rhs.x;
        (*this).y += rhs.y;
        return *this;
    }
};
```

Along with the following operators (they're not `friend`s because there's no private members to access).

```
template<typename T = int>
inline coord<T> operator-(coord<T> lhs, const coord<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs -= rhs;
    return lhs;
}

template<typename T = int>
inline coord<T> operator+(coord<T> lhs, const coord<T>& rhs)
{
    lhs += rhs;
    return lhs;
}
```

Elsewhere in my code I have another class `A` with a method that looks like this:

```
void A::SetVarC(coord<int>& c)
{
    m_c = c;
}
```

(assume there's a getter for `m_c` as well)

When I try to invoke this method using the addition and subtraction operators I overloaded:

```
int x = 1;
int y = 1;

A* a = new A();

coord c1(1,2);

a->SetVarC(c1 - a->GetVarC() + coord<int>(x,y));
```

I get an error that there's no known conversion from `coord<int>` to `coord<int>&`. I can see that my subtraction and addition operators aren't returning references, but I thought that wouldn't matter. I am using C++11... are move semantics coming into play here?

Comment: would changing lhs help? "inline coord<T> operator+(const coord<T>& lhs, const coord<T>& rhs);"

Comment: You are trying to bind an xvalue to an lvalue-reference. No wonder it does not work.

Comment: @AngelKoh That would be a bad idea, the `operator+` is implemented using `operator+=`, i. e. it changes its first argument.

Comment: Show `getVarC()` declaration

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You're creating arithmetic operators with a side affect...
These operators shouldn't change the value of the arguments used.

And, to the answer your question, these methods return a temporary object, that can't be passed as reference to `SetVarC`.

```
template<typename T = int>
inline coord<T> operator-(const coord<T>& lhs, const coord<T>& rhs)
{
    coord<T> res(lhs)
    res -= rhs;
    return res;
}

template<typename T = int>
inline coord<T> operator+(const coord<T>& lhs, const coord<T>& rhs)
{
    coord<T> res(lhs)
    res += rhs;
    return res;
}
```

Comment: It's perfectly fine modifying an argument passed by value.

Comment: @Deduplicator yes, but that's not the Meaning of the operator. an operator + between 2 items should return the result of the operation, not change one of the items. To have a clear API you must keep the standard definitions, or else you'll may suffer from side effects that are harder to find.

Comment: You're returning a reference to a temporary. (also, [see here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7592741/1012936) for why pass-by-value is reasonable here)

Comment: @milleniumbug Yes, that was a mistake.

Answer (score 5):

Temporary cannot be bind to non const reference, change `SetVarC` to

```
void A::SetVarC(const coord<int>& c)
{
    m_c = c;
}
```

or

```
void A::SetVarC(coord<int> c)
{
    m_c = std::move(c);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are passing a temporary `coord<int>` object to `A::SetVarC()` which requires a non-const reference, which is not possible.

You should fix your code by changing `A::SetVarC()` to accept a `const coord<int>&`.

Comment: did you mean `A::SetVarC()` which requires a "non-const" or "const" reference?

Comment: @MarsonMao No. You can't pass a `const` object to a reference that is not `const`.