# Initialize a const class member with a default value

Tags: c++, constructor, constants

I have two classes `A` and `B`. `bclass` of type `B` is a constant member of class `A`; what I want to do is to initialize class `bclass` with default values if no `B` object is provided to `A`.
Something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
  B(string Bs): Bstring(Bs){
    cout << "B constructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }

  ~B(){
    cout << "B destructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }

private:
  const string Bstring;
};

class A{
public:
  A(const B subb = B("mmmmm")): bclass(subb){
    cout << "A constructor." << endl;
  }

  ~A(){
    cout << "A destructor." << endl;
  }

private:
  const B bclass;
};

int main(void){
    A a;
    cout << "doing work..." << endl;
    sleep(2);
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
B constructor: mmmmm
A constructor.
B destructor: mmmmm
doing work...
A destructor.
B destructor: mmmmm
```

The thing is that I'm constructing 2 B classes(?) when only one is needed!
And somehow, B constructor is called only once, while the destructor is called twice... What is going on?!

**EDIT 1:**

After reading the (great) response of @WhiZTiM, I added the next two updates...

The next code explains when the second constructor is called:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
  B(string Bs): Bstring(Bs){
    cout << "B constructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }
  B(const B& bobj): Bstring(bobj.Bstring + "(copy)"){
    cout << "B copy constructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }

  ~B(){
    cout << "B destructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }

private:
  const string Bstring;
};

class A{
public:
  A(const B& subb = B("mmmmm")): bobj(subb){
    cout << "A constructor." << endl;
  }

  ~A(){
    cout << "A destructor." << endl;
  }

private:
  const B bobj;
};

int main(void){
  A a;
  cout << "doing work..." << endl;
  sleep(2);
  return 0;
}
```

output:

```
B constructor: mmmmm
B copy constructor: mmmmm(copy)
A constructor.
B destructor: mmmmm
doing work...
A destructor.
B destructor: mmmmm(copy)
```

As @WhiZTiM pointed to me, the compiler elided a third call to the B constructor (Thanks!).

**EDIT 2:**
As I want only 1 B object, the best idea is to use pointers. The code must be:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <unistd.h>

using namespace std;

class B{
public:
  B(const string Bs): Bstring(Bs){
    cout << "B constructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }
  B(const B& bobj): Bstring(bobj.Bstring){
    cout << "copying an existing B object." << endl;
  }

  ~B(){
    cout << "B destructor: " << Bstring << endl;
  }

private:
  const string Bstring;
};

class A{
public:
  A(B* subb = new B("mmmmm")): objb(subb){
    cout << "A constructor." << endl;
  }

  ~A(){
    cout << "A destructor." << endl;
    delete objb;
  }

private:
  const B* const objb;
};

int main(void){
  A a1; // This will call the default B constructor.
  A a2(new B("ooooo"));// This is calling a non default B object constructor.
  cout << "doing work..." << endl;
  sleep(2); //I need more motivation...
  return 0;
}
```

This is the output:

```
B constructor: mmmmm
A constructor.
B constructor: ooooo
A constructor.
doing work...
A destructor.
B destructor: ooooo
A destructor.
B destructor: mmmmm
```

Thanks a lot to [@WhiZTiM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1621391/whiztim)

Comment: `B` is not a constant sub-class. `A` is a composite object of `B`

Comment: Prefer `A(const B& subb = B("mmmmm"))`. `A(const B subb = B(...))` is a pretty bad idea because you cannot `move` a `const` object... Or better still [pass-by-value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11) `A(B subb = B("mmmmm"))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The thing is that I'm constructing 2 B classes(?) when only one is
>   needed! And somehow, B constructor is called only once, while the
>   destructor is called twice... What is going on?!

There is no magic going on. The compiler generated implicit copy and move constructors.
To get the true picture, implement yours

---

```
class A{
public:
  A(const B subb = B("mmmmm")): bclass(subb){
    cout << "A constructor." << endl;
  }

  ~A(){
    cout << "A destructor." << endl;
  }

private:
  const B bclass;
};
```

In your constructor, `B` is created using your single argument constructor, then assigned to `subb`, it is then copied to `bclass`... So there were actually 3 instances of `B` created.

- The first is your User-defined constructor, *which is why you see your output*
- The second is a move constructor used to construct `subb` *- compiler generated default*
- The third is a copy constructor used to construct `bclass` *- compiler generated default*

You may have seen 2 because, the compiler [elided a call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12953127/what-are-copy-elision-and-return-value-optimization)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You cleared me a lot of things. Now, what can you suggest if I NEED only one B object to be constructed?

Comment: I changed the A class. Now 'bclass' is 'const B* bclass;' and changed the 'A' constructor to 'A(B* subb = new B("mmmmm")): bclass(subb){' and it works great!