# What is the most efficient way of regulating memory when passing arrays as arguments?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, neural-network, instantiation

I learned to program in Python and am just now learning C++ so I apologize if the terms I use aren't conventional (also don't have a comp. sci. education or background).

I'm trying to build a neuron in C++. Weights are usually passed as arrays. When instantiating neurons, I need to pass an array of weights. I've been trying to get the neuron object to just reference the pointer so I don't have to make a copy, but I keep doing something wrong. Could somebody change this code so I'm not making a copy of the array and then explain what you did, and why you did it?

```
class Neuron {
    private:
        double bias;
        int num_weights;
        double weights[];
    public:
        Neuron(double*, int, double);
        double forward_prop(double[]);
};

Neuron::Neuron(double weights[], int num_weights, double bias) {
    this->num_weights = num_weights;
    this->bias = bias;
    // rotate through weights pointer and reassign to object attribute 'weights'
    for (int i=0;i<this->num_weights;i++) {
        this->weights[i] = weights[i];
    }
    // TODO: delete pointer

}

double Neuron::forward_prop(double values[]) {
    double output = this->bias;

    for (int i=0; i < this->num_weights; i++) {
        output += this->weights[i] * values[i];
    }
    return output;

}
```

Comment: In your class `double weights[];` is not legal C++.

Comment: If you want to avoid copying the 'array' (actually it's a pointer) then just copy the pointer `this->weights = weights;`. It's debateable (to say the least) whether that's a good idea, but that is how you would do it.

Comment: You also don't need to specify `this->` in almost all of the places you are using it.  -- *I learned to program in Python* -- One word of warning: do not use Python (or any other language) as a model in writing proper C++ code.

Comment: *I've been trying to get the neuron object to just reference the pointer so I don't have to make a copy* -- Then which entity owns the pointer?  Is it the `Neuron` object, or is it the caller?

Comment: I removed the [] in `double weights[];` and removed `this->` where there wasn't a shared name. An error popped up: `this->weights` is not an array, pointer, or vector. John, you said that I shouldn't use the pointer if possible. Is there a reason that using an array copy (or another method that I'm unaware of) is better (safer)? PaulMckenzie, if I could simply transfer ownership (i.e. accessible by the object but no longer accessible by the caller) that would be ideal. I've only been playing around with C++ for a few days now and am still learning how low-level languages work.

Comment: @DominicTarro -- See my answer below.

Comment: *I've only been playing around with C++ for a few days now and am still learning how low-level languages work* -- My opinion (and the opinion of many C++ experts) will state that you should skip the low-level parts of the language in the beginning and focus on creating easy-to-maintain, bug free code.  The low-level parts can come later, and don't be surprised if you seldom, if ever, need to use those parts of the language.

Comment: My end goal to develop a performance library that I can call in Python for fast computations (it's about finance and trading which is all about speed). Should I still ignore the low-level aspects for now?

Comment: I think you should still stick to writing high-level code, but using modern techniques (example, move-semantics, using data structures that have good cache-locality, etc).  If there is a performance issue (after measuring with a profiler), then consider low-level techniques using pointers.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a rewrite of your class, without object copying, and using the C++ standard library.  The example below uses `std::vector` along with move-semantics to avoid copying the data.  Comments come after the code sample:

```
#include <vector>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

class Neuron 
{
    private:
        std::vector<double> weights;  // We use a vector of doubles, not an array
        double bias; 

    public:
    
        Neuron(std::vector<double>&, double);
        double forward_prop(const std::vector<double>&);
};

Neuron::Neuron(std::vector<double>& weights_, double bias_) : weights(std::move(weights_)), bias(bias_) // The std::move avoids the copy
{}

double Neuron::forward_prop(const std::vector<double>& values) 
{
    // the std::inner_product function does what your code is doing now
    return std::inner_product(weights.begin(), weights.end(), values.begin(), bias);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<double> myWeights {1,2,3,4};
    Neuron n(myWeights, 10);
    std::cout << n.forward_prop({5,6,7,8});
}
```

Output:

```
80
```

Here are the key points:

1. The `std::vector` is used instead of arrays and pointers.  Note that we no longer need a `num_weights` member variable, since a vector knows its own size already by calling the `size()` member function of `std::vector`.
2. In the `Neuron` constructor, we issue a call to `std::move` when we're assigning the passed-in vector to the objects' member.  This invokes the move-semantics that are built into `std::vector`.  Basically the pointer(s) that the source vector uses are "stolen" or moved into the destination vector, thus avoiding the copy.

**Note that the source vector will be changed when this is done**.  The passed-in vector will essentially become empty (remember that the contents of it were moved out).

3. To top things off, I implemented your `forward_prop` using [std::inner_product](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/inner_product).
4. Additional items -- note the usage of the member-initialization list when writing the constructors.  Also, the call to `forward_prop` utilizes the brace-initialization syntax of `std::vector`, that's why when we called `forward_prop`, there was no need to explicitly declare a `std::vector<double>`.

---

Note that the real point to take away from this is that starting with C++11, move-semantics were formally introduced into the language.  This allows moving (instead of copying) to be done in a formal way.

With move-semantics now possible, additional functions were added (such as `std::move`, move constructors and move-assignment operators, `emplace_back` member functions in some STL container classes, `std::unique_ptr` works instead of the somewhat broken `std::auto_ptr`, etc.).

Before C++11, you had to do pointer "tricks" or hope that the compiler's optimizer implicitly did moving (even though there was no formal name for this type of operation).

Comment: [I'd consider it better style to have `Neuron::Neuron(std::vector<double> weights, double bias)` and do `Neuron n(std::move(myWeights), 10);` instead.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7592630/is-pass-by-value-a-reasonable-default-in-c11) Makes it clear that `myWeights` is gone after `n` is constructed.

Comment: Yes, that can be done also.  The point that we're both making is essentially that move-semantics fulfills the OP's wishes of not having the copy done.